# R: Join two tables (tibbles) by *list* columns

Tags: r, list, join, tidyverse, tibble

Seems like there should be a simple answer for this but I haven't been able to find one:

```
tib1 <- tibble(x = list(1, 2, 3), y = list(4, 5, 6))
tib1
# A tibble: 3 × 2
      x         y
 <list>    <list>
1 <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
2 <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
3 <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>

tib2 <- tibble(x = list(1, 2, 4, 5), y = list(4, c(5, 10), 6, 7))
tib2
# A tibble: 4 × 2
      x         y
 <list>    <list>
1 <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
2 <dbl [1]> <dbl [2]>
3 <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
4 <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>

dplyr::inner_join(tib1, tib2)
```

> Joining, by = c("x", "y")
>
> Error in inner_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) : 
>         Can't join on 'x' x 'x' because of incompatible types (list / list)

So is there a way to perform a join based on *list* columns (before I start writing my own)?

Basically if the list of both key variables is identical, I want the row to be included in the final table, and if not - not. In the above example there are two key variables `x` and `y` and the result should be only the first row in the two `tibble`s since it's the only identical one in both key variables:

```
tibble(x = list(1), y = list(4))
# A tibble: 1 × 2
      x         y
 <list>    <list>
1 <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
```

Comment: _So is there a way to perform a join based on list columns_, I don't think so, no. You could calculate a unique identifier first and join on that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use hashes from `digest`:

```
tib1 <- tibble(x = list(1, 2, 3), y = list(4, 5, 6))
tib2 <- tibble(x = list(1, 2, 4, 5), y = list(4, c(5, 10), 6, 7))

tib1 <- mutate_all(tib1, funs(hash = map_chr(., digest::digest)))
tib2 <- mutate_all(tib2, funs(hash = map_chr(., digest::digest)))

inner_join(tib1, tib2, c('x_hash', 'y_hash')) %>%
  select(x.x, x.y)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 1 × 2
>         x.x       x.y
>      <list>    <list>
> 1 <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
> ```

Comment: Nice, I just wrote something similar as we speak: `uniqueIdentifier <- function(l) paste(sort(l), collapse = " ")` and used `map_chr` as well.

Comment: We may have a bug when, say, the second element in `tib1` `y` is `c(10, 5)`, meaning `c(5, 10)` not in the same order. If the user doesn't care about order (true in my case) your method needs an extra `sort`, like in my function.