# Join across/within nested dataframes

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am pulling information out of a model for eventual plotting. My desired plots are jittered original data with an overlay of mean +/- STDERR and text groupings. The model outputs put the groupings and estimates in separate dataframes within a list. I'm using map to extract those and it works, but I'm stuck with the step of joining them together.

I want to join two nested list-cols into a single table and nest that result as a new column. Best I can do currently is to unnest, join tables, nest again, and join back to original nested table.

```
library(agricolae)
library(tidyverse)

fitHSD2<- function(d) HSD.test(aov(mpg ~ cyl, data= d), trt = "cyl")     # anova with Tukey HSD

carnestdf <-
    mtcars %>%
        group_by(gear) %>%
        nest() %>%
        mutate(mod = map(data, fitHSD2) # fit model
                        , estimates = map(mod, function(df) return(df$means)) # pull out estimates and StdErr
                        , estimates = map(estimates, function(df) return(rownames_to_column(df, var = "trt"))) #attach rownames as column for unnest
                        , grouping = map(mod, function(df) return(df$groups)) # pull out groupings
                        , grouping = map(grouping, function(df) mutate(df, trt = as.character(trt) # convert to character
                                                                                                        , trt = gsub("[[:space:]]*$", "", trt)
                                                                                                        , M = as.character(M)
                                                                                                        )
                                                    ) # remove whitespace at end for join
                        ) 

carnestdf
```

I can unnest each one and join them, but <del>I can't nest and join them back.</del> I can in fact... just need to define the join key otherwise it tries to join based upon the nested DF and that doesn't work without the hashing below.

```
full_join(unnest(carnestdf , estimates), unnest(carnestdf , grouping)) %>%
group_by(gear) %>%
nest(.key = "estgrp") %>%
full_join(carnestdf, ., by = "gear")
```

I found this: [R: Join two tables (tibbles) by *list* columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886700/r-join-two-tables-tibbles-by-list-columns)

<del>But it doesn't seem to work, I get the same error when using the hash to join.</del> It does work, needed to define the .key in nest so it wasn't "data". Would still prefer to join without unnesting... :/

```
nestmerge <-
    full_join(unnest(carnestdf , estimates), unnest(carnestdf , grouping)) %>%
    group_by(gear) %>%
    nest(.key = "mergedestgrp") %>%
    mutate_all(funs(hash = map_chr(., digest::digest)))

carnestdf %>%
    mutate_all(funs(hash = map_chr(., digest::digest))) %>%
    full_join(., nestmerge) %>%
    select(-ends_with("hash"))
```

Comment: For clarification, I'd be happy with a solution that joins the two within the nested dataframe, or extracting, joining, and joining back to nested dataframe as new column.

Answer (score 0):

The answer apparently is map2:

```
carnestdf <-
    mtcars %>%
        group_by(gear) %>%
        nest() %>%
        mutate(mod = map(data, fitHSD2) # fit model
                        , estimates = map(mod, function(df) return(df$means)) # pull out estimates and StdErr
                        , estimates = map(estimates, function(df) return(rownames_to_column(df, var = "trt"))) #attach rownames as column for unnest
                        , grouping = map(mod, function(df) return(df$groups)) # pull out groupings
                        , grouping = map(grouping, function(df) mutate(df, trt = as.character(trt) # convert to character
                                                                                                        , trt = gsub("[[:space:]]*$", "", trt)
                                                                                                        , M = as.character(M)
                                                                                                        )
                                                    ) # remove whitespace at end for join
                        , estgrp = map2(estimates, grouping, ~full_join(.x, .y, by = "trt"))
                        ) 

carnestdf
```

This does a full join on the two tables by "trt" and makes a new list column with the result.