# Using setdiff on dataframes with list columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there an R function to get the rows that are in one data.frame but not in another, if the data.frames contain list-columns? I know dplyr::setdiff will work on regular data.frames, but if I apply it to a data.frame with a list-column, I get an error.

```
list_df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 2))
list_df1$y <- list(c("A", "B"), c("C"), c("B", "C"))
list_df2 <- data.frame(x = c(2, 3))
list_df2$y <- list(c("C"), c("D", "E"))
dplyr::setdiff(list_df1, list_df2)
#> Error: Can't join on 'y' x 'y' because of incompatible types (list / list)
```

Currently I've been using a loop over the rows in both data.frames and directly comparing if the rows are equal:

```
in_df2 <- rep(FALSE, nrow(list_df1))
for (row_ind1 in seq_len(nrow(list_df1))) {
  for (row_ind2 in seq_len(nrow(list_df2))) {
    rows_equal <- all.equal(list_df1[row_ind1, ], 
                            list_df2[row_ind2, ], 
                            check.attributes = FALSE)
    if (isTRUE(rows_equal)) {
      in_df2[row_ind1] <- TRUE
      break
    }
  }
}
list_df1[!in_df2, ]
#>   x    y
#> 1 1 A, B
#> 3 2 B, C
```

And while gives the result I'm looking for, I'm sure there must be a better or more efficient solution.

dplyr::anti_join is also a possible solution, if the non-list columns uniquely identify the results. But in this case, I want to remove rows only if *all* entries are identical between the two data.frames. If we apply anti_join on just column x we don't get the results I'm looking for:

```
dplyr::anti_join(list_df1, list_df2, by = "x")
#>   x    y
#> 1 1 A, B
```

And applying it to all columns gives an error, just list set_diff

```
dplr::anti_join(list_df1, list_df2)
#> Error: Can't join on 'y' x 'y' because of incompatible types (list / list)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What you're trying to do is known as *merge* (base R) or *join* (dplyr or SQL). To find rows that are *not* in another table is an *anti join*. One solution is found in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886700/r-join-two-tables-tibbles-by-list-columns)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that question, it looks like it has some ideasI can work with. But `dplyr::anti_join` gives the same error `Error: Can't join on 'y' x 'y' because of incompatible types (list / list)`

Comment: See the linked SO question in my previous comment. It uses non-list columns created from the list columns as key columns for merging. I mentioned the terms to help your search in case you don't want to follow that solution

Comment: I get the exact desired result with `anti_join(list_df1, list_df2, by = 'x')` - please clarify your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that the ability to apply setdiff to data.frames with list-columns is not built into R or dplyr at the moment. However, it is possible to implement a solution that's significantly faster than the naive approach of looping over both
data.frames.

Option 1: If the list-columns aren't needed to identify the different rows, then dplyr::anti_join() is a great solution. To join by all non-list columns you could use (assuming list_df1 and list_df2 have the same column names):

```
nonlist_setdiff <- function(list_df1, list_df2) {
  nonlist_vars <- list_df1 %>%
    select_if(function(x) !is.list(x)) %>%
    colnames(.)
  dplyr::anti_join(list_df1, list_df2, by = nonlist_vars)
}
```

Option 2: If the list-columns are need to identify the different rows, then anti_join() is no longer an option. Instead, you can create a hash of each row of both data.frames, turning them into character vectors. Then you can apply setdiff to the character vectors. This approach uses the digest, dplyr, and purrr packages:

```
digest_setdiff <- function(list_df1, list_df2) {
  hash1 <- list_df1 %>%
    purrr::transpose() %>% # Transposing helps speed up the calculations
    purrr::map_chr(digest::digest, algo = "xxhash64") #use xxhash64 for speed
  hash2 <- list_df2 %>%
    purrr::transpose() %>%
    purrr::map_chr(digest::digest, algo = "xxhash64")
  only_in_df1 <- setdiff(hash1, hash2)
  list_df1[hash1 %in% only_in_df1, ]
}
```

This approach should work for all types of data.frames, no matter how complicated, and 
it's significantly faster than the naive approach. However, it is still way slower than the dplyr::setdiff and dplyr::anti_join commands, so don't use it if you don't have to.

Running digest_setdiff on your test input data gives the desired result:

```
digest_setdiff(list_df1, list_df2)
#>   x    y
#> 1 1 A, B
#> 3 2 B, C
```